# 2.0 tags API returns only created tags

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, api-v2

Searching for tags, using the inname parameter AND a date range returns only the tags that were created in that period, not the tags that were used in that period. When searching by inname only, or date range only the API returns all tags used (matching the criteria).

See this example: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/tags?fromdate=1322697600&todate=1325116800&order=desc&sort=activity&inname=java&site=stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `min` and `max` here if you want tags that were active in that range.  `fromdate` and `todate` always apply to creation.

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/tags?min=1322697600&max=1325116800&order=desc&sort=activity&inname=java&site=stackoverflow

returns

```
{"items":
  [{"name":"java-2d",
    "count":241,
    "is_required":false,
    "is_moderator_only":false
   },
   {"name":"r.java-file",
    "count":55,
    "is_required":false,
    "is_moderator_only":false
   },
   ...
  ]
}
```